# Why is JQuery Ajax returning successfully but showing an error in firebug in PHP app?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which when submitted is checked by the JQuery validator plugin.  This works fine.  In the JQuery code though I have my submit handler.
This part looks like the following:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "php/main.php",
         data: $(form).serialize()
     });
     return false;
 }
```

Now I dont see anything wrong with this, looks fine to me.  Then in main.php, I simply do

```
<?php
var_dump("OK");
include("APIEmailConnection.php");
var_dump("OK2");

if (isset($_POST["emailAddress"]) && !empty($_POST["emailAddress"])){
    var_dump("OK3");
    $connection = new APIEmailConnection();
    $connection->obtainConnection();
    var_dump("OK4");
}
```

I dont show it above, but I have a success function in my ajax call, and everytime I submit my form with an email address the success is fired.  However, if I check firebug, I see the error

> Fatal error: Class 'APIEmailConnection' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/myurl.com/httpdocs/folder/php/main.php on line 12

Also, the outputs from my var_dumps are

```
string(2) "OK"
string(3) "OK2"
string(3) "OK3"
```

So its missing OK4.  My folder structure is like so

```
index.html
    --js
        --main.js
    --php
        --main.php
        --APIEmailConnection.php
```

Now php include should be relative to the current file location, and because I am in main.php I believe my include is the correct path.  And my submit handler must be correct, otherwise main.php would never be called in the first place.

So my question is what am I doing wrong?  I dont know if it makes a difference, but main.php is a standard php file whereas APIEmailConnection.php is a class (and I dont namespace it).

Any advice on what the problem could be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try this `include(dirname(_ _FILE_ _)."/APIEmailConnection.php");` without the spaces between the underscores

Comment: Double check the class name in APIEmailConnection.php matches what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the relevence to the section from which you include or use  the **main.php** file. Hope this helps.